# Specifying Apache Arrow partitioning from file names in R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am learning Apache Arrow with R and I am trying to get a better understanding of
the partitioning mechanisms.

I have a folder with more than 5 000 CSV files that have that
structure: `cci_v4_2004106_ppz_takuvik_above_45n.csv`

```r
library(arrow)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arrow'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     timestamp

ds <- open_dataset("~/Desktop/ppz/", format = "csv")

ds
#> FileSystemDataset with 5824 csv files
#> longitude: double
#> latitude: double
#> primary_production: double
```

Is it possible to infer the partitioning from the filenames? For instance, I would like to use something like:

```r
# ds <- open_dataset("~/Desktop/ppz/", format = "csv", partitioning = c("year", "yday"))
```

Can I define a schema such as `partitioning = c("year", "yday")` takes the values from the filename (here: year = 2004, yday = 106).

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this feature does not exist today.  Partitioning is currently limited to directories:

```
/2014/106/ppz_takuvik_above_45n.csv           // "directory" flavor
/year=2014/yday=106/ppz_takuvik_above_45n.csv // "hive" flavor
```

There is an [open JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14612) for filename based partitioning and there is a PR under review for this so I expect it will become available in 8.0.0.

However, that ticket won't do exactly what you are describing.  It will allow you to treat each underscore-separated element as a column but it won't split the `2014106` column into `year/yday`.  If you could change your filenames to `2014_106` on the other hand I think you would be ok.